# Are there any good options for creating functional windows forms for C?

Tags: c, user-interface, ide

I have been learning C# and use Microsoft Visual Studio which makes it very easy and enjoyable to create windows forms with various controls like progress bars, drop down menus, file-system browsers etc..

Can the same thing be done with C, and are there any recommended programs?

(I have learned some C and would like to make graphical interfaces a step further than just in the console, I guess this is quite hard?).

Comment: There is no standard way of creating GUI in C, so you will need to find a library that enables you to do so. I'm not familiar with it, but QT might be a good cross-platform option for you

Comment: Attila, on Windows you can certainly use the API directly. No library required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The windows API was (and still is) a C API. Documented on [msdn.microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632588%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The simplest way to create a Windows application with a simple form, in C, without using any external frameworks is this program:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "Resource.h"

BOOL CALLBACK   DialogProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  switch(uMsg)
  {
  case WM_INITDIALOG:
    return TRUE;
  }
  return FALSE;
}

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,HINSTANCE hNull, LPTSTR cmdLine, int cmdShow)
{
  return DialogBoxParam(hInstance,MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_MAINDIALOG),NULL,DialogProc,0L);
}
```

The assumption is that, in addition to this `main.c` file, you use the Visual Studio resource editor to create a resource script file (.rc) with a dialog resource that you lay out your controls on.
If you are using Visual Studio Express a resource editor is not included and you will need a 3rd party editor (they are available) to lay out the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

GTK+ at http://www.gtk.org/documentation.php

Comment: I will experiment with this too, different look to it, thanks very much.

Comment: FYI, GTK+ makes more sense than the win API (imho). Moreover it's cross platform. the question now is; why on earth are you building a GUI using C? if it's constraints related okey, otherwise it's time to migrate to something else that is meant for such purposes :)